# Using 3rd Party Shared Object Library and header files in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to use this ZED Open Capture library for using the ZED Mini camera for my project on RaspberryPi. I succesfully installed the library and the shared object file is at `/usr/local/lib/libzed_open_capture.so` and the include headers are at the location `/usr/local/include/zed-open-capture/`.
To include this library I am adding the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_library(ZED_LIB zed_open_capture) 

include_directories("/usr/local/include/zed-open-capture/")

add_executable(zed_pub src/zed_pub.cpp)

target_link_libraries(zed_pub ${ZED_LIB})
```

Now when I use this code , it shows this error `"‘sl_oc::video’ has not been declared`"

```
#include "videocapture.hpp" //Library Header File
sl_oc::video::VideoCapture cap;
cap.initializeVideo();
const sl_oc::video::Frame frame = cap.getLastFrame();
```

- Can someone please explain me how a Shared Object Library file along with header files should be used in CMake? The library has already been installed using CMake build and `sudo make install` on my Linux system.

The github repo of the library is at https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-open-capture

Also I cannot find Find_PKG_name.cmake so I cannot use find_package() option.

Comment: Does `videocapture.hpp` actually contain the required symbol? Do you compile your code with C++ compiler (not C)? Remember to put `cmake_minimum_required` and `project(MyProject LANGUAGES CXX)` in your root `CMakeLists.txt`. As for Find module, you are supposed to write it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I am even able to find the references in VSCode for sl_oc::video::VideoCapture.

And do you have any reference for Find_Pkg.cmake creation which I can refer. Shouldn't the creation of Find_Pkg.cmake file be handled by CMakelists.txt of the library?

Comment: What are the compile commands then? There is a small tutorial which covers find-module creation: https://izzys.casa/2020/12/how-to-find-packages-with-cmake-the-basics/. And yes, contrary to find-modules, there are also config-modules which should be provided by library through cmake install mechanisms, but it's not uncommon for libraries to not provide it, so you often need to resort to writing find-modules.

Comment: I am just using cmake .. and make command to build the project. Thank you for the link.

Comment: According to the header [videocapture.hpp](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-open-capture/blob/master/include/videocapture.hpp#L46), it provides namespace `sl_oc::video` **only if** macro `VIDEO_MOD_AVAILABLE` is defined. Aside adding proper include directories and linking with proper libraries, you need to add proper compile definitions. And make sure that these definitions corresponds to the library which you have. E.g. definition `VIDEO_MOD_AVAILABLE` is enabled for the library build with enabled option `BUILD_VIDEO` (this option is set by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`videocapture.hpp` wraps the definitions you need inside `#ifdef VIDEO_MOD_AVAILABLE`.  It seems likely that this is not defined.  The root CMakeLists.txt in the ZED package defaults BUILD_VIDEO to ON, so this was likely all defined for the package build.  But as others have pointed out, the package does not persist this information anywhere in the installation.  The "right" way for the package to do it would be EITHER to configure/modify the include files at install time to account for the build configuration, probably by generating a "config.hpp" file with the appropriate definitions.  OR to include a `zed-config.cmake` file in the installation, with all the necessary imports and definitions.

Your short-circuit solution should be fine.  Just add `target_compile_definitions(zed_pub PUBLIC VIDEO_MOD_AVAILABLE)`.  If you want to do it more cleanly for the future, create an IMPORTED target for zed_lib, and set both the `include_directories` and `compile_definitions` on that target, so that all users of the library get this defined automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the suggested method of target_compile_definitions worked for me. I am able to compile the code with the Zed library. However when I change the build type to ament_cmake so that I can put this code inside a ROS2 wrapper it is still unable to find the `sl::video namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ZED Open Capture's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
# Install rules
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HDR_FULL}"
)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/zed-open-capture)
```

ref:  https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-open-capture/blob/dfa0aee51ccd2297782230a05ca59e697df496b2/CMakeLists.txt#L142-L148

ZED Open Capture seems to **not** provide any "CMake config" file...

So you must create your own `FindZED.cmake` module and/or improve the CMakeLists.txt of this project...

Comment: I tried using add_library( ) option of CMAKE as a way around creating my own FindZed.cmake, but it is not working. Is defining FindPkg.cmake config-file the only way to go about this or there are other options too? 
'''
add_library(zed_lib SHARED IMPORTED) set_property(TARGET zed_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/path/to/zed_lib.so") 
'''